# How to add Delay before finding GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay, unityscript

I am trying to make a game in where you can stab an enemy, the enemy struggles for about a second and drops dead. (ragdoll);

i think its best to just show my script and you know what I mean:

In an on trigger enter script:

```c#
if(other.tag == "enemy"){
    other.transform.parent.gameObject.name = ("enemy" + currentEnemy);
    print(other.name);
    gameObject.Find("enemy" + currentEnemy).GetComponent("RagdollOrNot").MakeKinematicFalse();
    BloodParticle.emit = true;
    Stabbed = true;
    Character.GetComponent("MouseLook").enabled = false;
    Character.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").enabled = false;

}
```

and in the update function:

```c#
if(Stabbed == true){
    StopBleeding ++;
}

if(StopBleeding > 50){
    Stabbed = false;
    StopBleeding = 0;
    currentEnemy ++;
    Character.GetComponent("MouseLook").enabled = true;
    Character.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").enabled = true;
    BloodParticle.emit = false;
}
```

Now when my knife enters the collision of the enemy the enemy imediatly drops to the floor.
I tried putting the:

```c#
gameObject.Find("enemy" + currentEnemy).GetComponent("RagdollOrNot").MakeKinematicFalse();
```

in the update function in `if(StopBleeding > 50)`.

if I do that I get an error of Null reverance exception becaus the script cand find the enemy. While it can I its in the trigger enter.

Basicly my question is: Is there any way to fix this error to give it a 50 frame delay (all the rest in `StopBleeding` works)?

Or is there any way I can put a simple delay in before the Ragdoll gets activated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use StartCoroutine("DelayDeath"); where DelayDeath is the name of a method. See below.

```
    if(other.tag == "enemy"){
    other.transform.parent.gameObject.name = ("enemy" + currentEnemy);
    print(other.name);
    StartCoroutine("DelayDeath");
    BloodParticle.emit = true;
    Stabbed = true;
    Character.GetComponent("MouseLook").enabled = false;
    Character.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").enabled = false;

}

private IEnumerator DelayDeath()
{
   //this will return...and one second later re-enter and finish the method
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
   gameObject.Find("enemy" +   currentEnemy).GetComponent("RagdollOrNot").MakeKinematicFalse();
}
```

Comment: Note, that's the C# syntax.  The Unity JS syntax doesn't require the use of Coroutines at all.  Look up Unity JS's "yield" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking specifically about Unity JS and not C#, you'll use the yield keyword.

```
 print("foo");
 yield WaitForSeconds (5.0); // waits for 5 seconds before executing the rest of the code
 print("bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

On stabbing you could look up the enemy object but save it away in a variable instead of issuing the enemies dead. After the bleeding finishes you don't have to look up the enemy and can trigger the death on the saved one.

Another hint: Don't count frames as frames might be of different length. Add up time from Time.deltaTime until you reach let's say 2 seconds and then trigger the death.

Hope that helps.